# Images on iOS load then disappear then when I go to settings and back to the page they re-appear

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I have made an html site which works fine, except when you open it on an IOS mobile device certain images don't load.

Well they load but after a second disappear. If I then go to settings on the iPhone and go back the images are loaded.

I have checked the Viewport, the sizes of the images, any differences in the code with other images that work fine but can't seem to find any solutions.

Please help.

The website is https://www.kemnet.be

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it looks more like an issue with your 'lazy loading' or javascript `window.onscroll`.

The staff images didn't really work for me on Safari on Mac either. They flickered for some seconds and then disappeared. I'm using: 
`(Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.2 Safari/605.1.15)`

Try removing all javascript (and the "preloader" div) and try again.
The site now works for me and the images do not flicker.

I took a quick peek in your `js/init.js` script, try disabling these three things:

- Section: Smooth scroll
- Section: Animate

```
//Pretty Photo
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    social_tools: false,
    theme: 'light_square'
});
```

and try going forward from there.